# How can I devote different separator for last item?

Tags: php, regex, implode

I'm trying to create a string from the elements of an array. Here is my array:

```
$arr = array ( 1 => 'one',
               2 => 'two',
               3 => 'three',
               4 => 'four' );
```

Now I want this **output:**

```
one, two, three and four
```

As you see in the output above, default seperator is `,` and last seperator is `and`.

---

Well, there is two PHP functions for doing that, [join()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) and [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). But none of them isn't able to accept different separator for last one. How can I do that?

**Note:** I can do that like this:

```
$comma_separated = implode(", ", $arr);
preg_replace('/\,([^,]+)$/', ' and $1', $comma_separated);
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/aNOeD)

---

Now I want to know is there any solution without regex?

Comment: What's wrong with my solution *(using regex)*? ... Actually that's a good question, But my solution sometimes fails. When the last value of array be containing comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use foreach and build your own implode();

```
function implode_last( $glue, $gluelast, $array ){
    $string = '';
    foreach( $array as $key => $val ){
        if( $key == ( count( $array ) - 1 ) ){
            $string .= $val.$gluelast;
        }
        else{
            $string .= $val.$glue;
        }
    }
    //cut the last glue at the end
    return substr( $string, 0, (-strlen( $glue )));
}

$array = array ( 1 => 'one',
           2 => 'two',
           3 => 'three',
           4 => 'four' );

echo implode_last( ', ', ' and ', $array );
```

If your Array starts with Index 0 you have to set `count( $array )-2`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$arr = array ( 1 => 'one',
           2 => 'two',
           3 => 'three',
           4 => 'four' );

$first_three     = array_slice($arr, 0, -1); 
$string_part_one = implode(", ", $first_three);  
$string_part_two = end($arr);   

echo $string_part_one.' and '.$string_part_two;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: More easy to use `array_pop` IMO: `$last = array_pop($arr); echo implode(', ', $arr) . ' and ' . $last;`